# show sum of items between rows in dynamic rows

Tags: jquery, group-by, sum

I am generating dynamic rows from json data with this code .

```
rowtemplate='';

$.each(jsonData, function(key, value){

rowtemplate=rowtemplate+'<tr>';
$.each(value, function(key1, value1){

objReportsInterface.rowtemplate=rowtemplate+'<td><center>'+value1+'</center></td>';

});

rowtemplate=rowtemplate+'</tr>';

});
```

this gives me output like

[image]

now i want to display sum of each type of category in last row of each item row like 
[image]

but not getting any idea .

i am trying to implement logic after append like

```
$('.tabletbody tr').each(function(){

//  show sum group by category
});
```

I search in forum . but every suggestion is to display in last rows . how can i generate in middle of rows ? plz suggest

Comment: Can you show how your json data is structured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the json data is already sorted by Item you can use a variable to check for item changes and output a summary row

```js
var jsonData = [{
  Qty: 3,
  Time: '04:00',
  Item: 'Avacado Stuffed Tomato',
  functionRoom: 'Living Room'
},
{
  Qty: 3,
  Time: '04:00',
  Item: 'Avacado Stuffed Tomato',
  functionRoom: 'Living Room'
},
{
  Qty: 1,
  Time: '04:00',
  Item: 'BBQ Dry Ruby Steak Skewer',
  functionRoom: 'Living Room'
},
{
  Qty: 1,
  Time: '04:00',
  Item: 'BBQ Dry Ruby Steak Skewer',
  functionRoom: 'Living Room'
}]

rowtemplate = '';
var sum = 0
var currentItem;

// Ensure that json data is grouped by Item

$.each(jsonData, function(key, value) {

  if(currentItem !== value.Item) {
    if (currentItem) {
       rowtemplate += '<tr><td>'+sum+'</td><td></td><td>Sum of '+currentItem+'</td></tr>'
    }
    currentItem = value.Item
    sum = 0
  }
  sum += Number(value.Qty)

  rowtemplate = rowtemplate + '<tr>';
  $.each(value, function(key1, value1) {
    
    rowtemplate += '<td><center>' + value1 + '</center></td>';
    
  });

  rowtemplate = rowtemplate + '</tr>';

});
rowtemplate += '<tr><td>'+sum+'</td><td></td><td>Sum of '+currentItem+'</td></tr>'

document.body.querySelector('table').innerHTML += rowtemplate
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table/>
```